# A committee of four people, containing at least one man and one woman, must be chosen from four men and three women.

Tags: combinatorics

A committee of four people, containing at least one man and one woman, must be chosen from four men and three women. How many different committees are possible?

Is the right answer 34?

(7x6x5x4x3)/(1x2x3x4) - 1

Comment: Yes, the number is $34$.

Comment: it looks like you have one extra term in the numerator, you meant 7x6x5x4/4! - 1 .